# Functional Test Not isolating from database

Tags: django, selenium

I am having a problem where my functional test is not isolating from the main database, there is data left over from the test. I ran python manage.py flush and the test works, but when I run the test again the data created by the test that should have been deleted is still there making my test fail. I am currently only using SQLite.

functional_test.py

```
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class NewUserTest(LiveServerTestCase):

def setUp(self):
    self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.browser.implicitly_wait(15)

def tearDown(self):
    self.browser.quit()

def test_user(self):
   #Some test
```

Comment: That is default behavior.  You need to explicitly delete any test data that you don't want after tests complete. One strategy is to drop/create the database each time, and only load a pre-set of know test fixtures before running you selenium tests.

Comment: @AronYsidoro do you know of anyway to automatically drop the data created by the test, without having to run manage.py flush after each test

Comment: Take a look at this question. Seems like a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17435155/django-functional-liveservertestcase-after-submitting-form-with-selenium-obje

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out, it actually had some thing to do with how the files were named inside of the functional_test folder. I had a more verbose name of test_this_thing.py and I renamed it tests.py and it worked for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to indent your method definitions (the statements that begin with "def"). As a result, the Python interpreter thinks that you've defined a new class, called NewUserTest, that contains no attributes, and three top-level functions.

To solve the problem, simply indent the "def" statements by an appropriate amount (4 spaces is the standard convention amongst the Python community). It should look like this:

```
class NewUserTest(LiveServerTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(15)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

...
```